# How to display html elements inside a div onclick?

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery code that will display elements onclick. The problem is that it shows plain text only, it should be in html format. Please help. Thank you.
[jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/kaxakuleri)

```
$(".click").click( function(){    
    $("#container").html("&lt;a href=&quot;&quot;&gt;display me as html&lt;/a&gt;");
});

  <span class='click'>Click me</span>

  <div id='container'>[data will appear here onclick]</div>
```

```js
$(".click").click( function(){    
    $("#container").html("&lt;a href=&quot;&quot;&gt;display me as html&lt;/a&gt;");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span class='click'>Click me</span>
  <div id='container'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can see that it is in HTML anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give the output with html entities:

```
$("#container").html("&lt;a href=&quot;&quot;&gt;display me as html&lt;/a&gt;");
```

Just use regular html code:

```
$("#container").html("<a href=''>display me as html</a>");
```

Comment: Hi dude, I'm gonna use this in blogger (blogspot) so I need it like that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8gL76pn8/)

```
$("#container").html('&lt;a href=&quot;&quot;&gt;display me as html&lt;/a&gt;').html($("#container").text());
```